# How can I remove the \n data when creating a JSON file in a Synapse notebook?

Tags: python, databricks, azure-synapse

I'm creating a JSON file in a Synapse notebook, but when ingesting the data into the data lake, it adds \n in one of its columns. How can I remove this?

I also tried removing the spaces from the data in that column, but it still continues to add \n in the file

this is the part of the code:

```
# Save each JSON output to Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2
output_file_path = f"{data_lake_path}/output_{unique_id}.json"
with fs.open(output_file_path, "w") as json_file:
    json.dump(result, json_file, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2)


Output:

"ColumnX": [
        "[\n        {\n            \"Example\": \"data1\"
      ]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
output_file_path = f"{data_lake_path}/output_{unique_id}.json"
with fs.open(output_file_path, "w") as json_file:
    json.dump(result, json_file, ensure_ascii=False, separators=(",", ":"))
```

In the updated code, the separators parameter is used to specify the separators between keys and values (":") and between items in an array (","), effectively removing any indentation and line breaks.

By using separators=(",", ":"), the resulting JSON will have a more compact format without unnecessary whitespace or line breaks. This should help avoid the addition of \n in your JSON file.

Make sure to adjust any other formatting requirements or specific needs you have for your JSON file.

Comment: I used this but I'm still getting the same data:
"ColumnX":["[\n        {\n            \"Example\": \"data1\"} "]]

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting this output is because you are dumping the result of type `string`.

```py
import json

print(type(r)) 
print(r)

output_file_path = f"output.json"
with open(output_file_path, "w") as json_file:
    json.dump(r, json_file, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2)
```

Output:

```
<class 'str'> 
{"ColumnX": [{"Example": "data1"}, {"Example": "data2"}]}
```

```bash
%%sh
head output.json
```

Output:

```
"{\n \"ColumnX\": [\n {\n \"Example\": \"data1\"\n },\n {\n \"Example\": \"data2\"\n }\n ]\n}"
```

To remove  `\n` and `\"`, you need to load the string and perform a JSON dump.

```py
output_file_path = f"output.json"
with open(output_file_path, "w") as json_file:
    json.dump(json.loads(r), json_file, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2)
```

Output:

[image: Output image]